# Restructure code from AngularJS to RailsBootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How can I Restructure this code to Rails bootstrap with 4 column grid :

```
<div ng-show="chooseNeighborhoodsVis">
  <div ng-repeat="hood in neighborhoods">
        <input type="checkbox" name="user[neighborhood_ids][]"
            value="{{ hood.id }}" ng-click="countHoods(hood.name)">{{ hood.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using twitter bootstrap then this wat you can do.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

    <!-- Your Code Goes Here -->

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">Column 3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">Column 4</div>
</div>
```